# Phonegap and iOS Notification Center widgets

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm building something like calendar application for iOS and I'd like to add widgets in notification center. Is it possible with phonegap? I can't find any plugins or examples.[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. This link is about native iOS applications. If there are no any ways to do widget with phonegap I will try to make native phonegap plugin, but now I'm interested in solutions for phonegap/cordova.

Comment: @KardanovIR: did you find a solution in the end. Did you make your own plugin?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find any solutions and just didn't make plugin.